# joining two xml's (4 datasets) for ssrs query reporting purpose?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I have two XML's :
First is;

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
<entity name="invoice">
<attribute name="name" />
<attribute name="customerid" />
<attribute name="totalamount" />
<attribute name="invoiceid" />
<attribute name="new_customerno" />
<order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="invoicedetail" from="invoiceid"  to="invoiceid" link-type="inner"> 
    <attribute name="new_styleno" />
    <attribute name="new_locationcode" />
    <attribute name="invoiceid"/>
    <attribute name="new_finalcmt" />
    </link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Second is;

```
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0">
<entity name="new_creditmemo">
<attribute name="new_creditmemoid"/>
<attribute name="new_name"/>
<attribute name="new_customerno"/>
<attribute name="new_customername"/>
<order descending="false" attribute="new_name"/>
    <link-entity name="new_creditmemoline" link-type="outer" to="new_creditmemoid" from="new_creditmemoid">
    <attribute name="new_name"/>
    <attribute name="new_creditmemoid"/>
    <attribute name="new_locationcode"/>
    <attribute name="new_finalcmt"/>
    <order descending="false" attribute="new_name"/>
    </link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Now I need to merge these two XML's on the basis of **new_customerno**. I have tried but it's not working. 
Can someone please help me with this ??
Thanks

Comment: Try http://www.sql2fetchxml.com if you have sql query in hand for what you are trying to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

Union statement is not available in FetchXml reports. To make it work you will have to look for alternatives. Here is one of possible solutions - https://butenko.pro/2012/11/09/ms-crm-2011-t-sql-union-operation-and-fetchxml-based-reports/

Comment: I guess OP is asking for another level link-entity between 2 fetchxml queries not union.. if am not wrong.,